# Disable Vertex AI Gemini API safety attributes

Tags: python, google-cloud-vertex-ai, google-gemini, google-generativeai

I am currently developing an application using `vertexai` API where I am uploading research paper and use prompt engineering to get the major content of the paper.

While I am triggering basic prompt like describe the context of the paper, I receive error `HARM_CATEGORY_UNSPECIFIED`. How do I disable it?

Provides the context of the paper or a summery.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is difficult to provide exact guidance for your problem, since you don't show us how you're calling Gemini or the exact results you're getting. Updating your question to include the code you used and the JSON reply you're getting should help us help you further. Remember, the more information you provide, the better our chances are of being able to help.

Answer (score 0):

While you don't provide details about what you're doing, a few notes in general about the safety settings for Gemini in Vertex AI:

Gemini rates it based on the probability of harm in four categories from least chance of harm to the most:

- NEGLIGIBLE
- LOW
- MEDIUM
- HIGH

By default, it will block a response if it feels it is "medium and above" in any of the categories it evaluates.

You can change this to other levels for each category. For example, this code would block it for LOW, MEDIUM, and HIGH:

```py
    # Safety config
    safety_config = {
        generative_models.HarmCategory.HARM_CATEGORY_DANGEROUS_CONTENT: generative_models.HarmBlockThreshold.BLOCK_LOW_AND_ABOVE,
        generative_models.HarmCategory.HARM_CATEGORY_HARASSMENT: generative_models.HarmBlockThreshold.BLOCK_LOW_AND_ABOVE,
    }

    # Generate content
    responses = model.generate_content(
        [image, "Add your prompt here"],
        generation_config=config,
        stream=True,
        safety_settings=safety_config,
    )
```

You *can* set it to `BLOCK_NONE` as well, however this won't always do what you expect. There are some things that Google is required to block even if you have it set to `BLOCK_NONE`. In these cases, it may indicate that the block category is "unspecified".

Answer (score 0):

Go to Gemini / safety settings:

```
HarmCategory.HARM_CATEGORY_DANGEROUS_CONTENT: HarmBlockThreshold.BLOCK_ONLY_HIGH,
HarmCategory.HARM_CATEGORY_HATE_SPEECH: HarmBlockThreshold.BLOCK_ONLY_HIGH,
HarmCategory.HARM_CATEGORY_HARASSMENT: HarmBlockThreshold.BLOCK_ONLY_HIGH,
HarmCategory.HARM_CATEGORY_SEXUALLY_EXPLICIT: HarmBlockThreshold.BLOCK_ONLY_HIGH
```

As @Prisoner said, `BLOCK_NONE`.

More info at the [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/generative-ai/multimodal/configure-safety-attributes)